# Show and Hide hidden <div> when radio input is checked

Tags: jquery, radio-button, show-hide

I just want to use this functionality many times without having to duplicate the script or found my self adding new selectors if I need to use it again. If you don't understand what I'm trying to say, this is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/wfA6m/5/).

```
$('.show-and-hide-content').click(function () {
  // Hide all
  $('.show-and-hide-true').hide('slideToggle');

  // Show checked
  if ($('#select-no').prop('checked')) {
    $('.show-and-hide-true').show('slideToggle');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You use same class and id for different actions. Look at this modified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wfA6m/6/)

```
$('.show-and-hide-content').click(function () {
    // Hide all
    $('.show-and-hide-true').hide('slideToggle');

    // Show checked
    if ($('#select-no').prop('checked')) {
        $('.show-and-hide-true').show('slideToggle');
    }
});

$('.show-and-hide-content2').click(function () {
    // Hide all
    $('.show-and-hide-false').hide('slideToggle');

    // Show checked
    if ($('#select-yes2').prop('checked')) {
        $('.show-and-hide-false').show('slideToggle');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wfA6m/10/)**

### HTML

```
<div class="show-and-hide-content">
    <input type="radio" data-type="true" />Yes
    <input type="radio" data-type="false" />No
    <div class="content content-false">You select NO</div>
    <div class="content content-true">You select YES</div>
</div>

<div class="show-and-hide-content">
    <input type="radio" data-type="true" />Yes
    <input type="radio" data-type="false" />No
    <div class="content content-false">You select NO</div>
    <div class="content content-true">You select YES</div>
</div>

<!-- other duplicates - same markup -->
```

### CSS

```
.show-and-hide-content .content { display: none; }
.show-and-hide-content .content-false { color: red; }
.show-and-hide-content .content-true { color: green; }
```

### jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $('.show-and-hide-content').each(function (i) {
        var $row = $(this);
        var $radios = $row.find('input');
        $radios.attr('name', 'group-' + i);
        $radios.on('change', function () {
            var type = $(this).attr('data-type');
            $row
                .find('.content').hide()
                .filter('.content-' + type)
                    .show();
        });

    });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this, you wanna show green text when checked values is 'YES'. And show red text when 'NO' value is checked?

You can also use multiple div of ".show-and-hide-content" with only this script.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/wfA6m/7/

Then, change radios' id to classes and use this script.

## JQUERY

```
$('.show-and-hide-content').click(function () {    
    if ($('input.select-no:checked').prop('checked')) {
        $(this).find('div.show-and-hide-false').show('slideToggle');
        $(this).find('div.show-and-hide-true').hide('slideToggle');
    }
    else{
        $(this).find('div.show-and-hide-true').show('slideToggle');
        $(this).find('div.show-and-hide-false').hide('slideToggle');
    }
});
```